# No Sound when KeyEvent added

Tags: audio, lua, coronasdk, keyevent

> After adding this piece of code I have lost the sounds of my game. Even the volume control button does not work while playing. Solution needed as soon as possible. Thanks.

```
Runtime:addEventListener( "key", onKeyEvent )

    function onKeyEvent( event )
        if (event.phase == "up" and event.keyName=="back") then
                goToTheMenu()
        end    
    end
```

Comment: This question is the equivalent of "I need you to solve the universe based on this star, and in a timely manner". If you want help, you need to provide plenty more information.

Comment: Do u see the answer that someone gave! Do u think that's solution of universe! Gave plenty information, those who have used the keyEvent can easily understand what i tried to mean.
What makes u think that i have not provided enough information! What more information do u want?

Answer (score 2):

Change your function to :

```
function onKeyEvent( event )
    local keyname = event.keyName;
    if (event.phase == "up" and (event.keyName=="back" or event.keyName=="menu" or event.keyName == "home" )) then
        if keyname == "menu" or keyname == "back" or keyname == "home" then
            goToMenu()
            return true
        end
    end
    return false
end
```